# What's the best Bluetooth mode to use for streaming data?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a microcontroller collecting sensor data at a rate of about 4 Hz. I would like to send this data over Bluetooth to a remote entity. I'm thinking the [serial port profile (SPP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Serial_Port_Profile_.28SPP.29) would be best, since it emulates a physical cable. Under normal usage, it would not be unreasonable to expect the connection to be held open for 10 to 12 hours at a time.

Has anyone done any work in this field? Does anyone know the best profile to use, or any resources to use as reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you already responded yourself to your question. Yes use SPP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup I'd use SPP/RFCOMM.  That will be supported in all Bluetooth versions and all implementations (except for the very very very basic which might not support RFCOMM/SPP).  There shouldn't be any problem with keeping the connection open for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth 2.1 supports a streaming mode over a basic RFCOMM channel, if your API will let you configure it.